# Virtual template member methods! A practical workaround

Tags: c++

I Have the following code:

```
class Output {  // This is called INTERFACE 
public:
template <class Iterable,
        class _begin = decltype(Iterable {}.begin()),
        class _end   = decltype(Iterable {}.end())>
    /* virtual ?? */ void write(const Iterable& messages) const
    {
        for (auto& message : messages) {
            cout << message << std::endl;
        }          
    }
};

class Derived : public Output { // Concrete class
public:
template <class Iterable,
        class _begin = decltype(Iterable {}.begin()),
        class _end   = decltype(Iterable {}.end())>
    void write(const Iterable& messages) const /* override ?? */
    {
        cout << "Report from drived class:" << std::endl; 
        for (auto& message : messages) {
            cout << "DR:" << message << std::endl;
        }          
    }
};

template <class Iterable,
        class _begin = decltype(Iterable {}.begin()),
        class _end   = decltype(Iterable {}.end())>
void do_write (Output &out, const Iterable& messages)
{   // I can not change this method. e.g. private API. 
    out.write(messages);
}

int main ()
{
    Derived output;
    do_write(output, {"Record 1", "Record 2"});

    return 0;
}
```

Yes. You are right. This is a sort of virtual template member method. Oom, Not yet! There a lot of texts about variuos workarounds mainly mentioned the **Type Erasure Idom**. Frankly, more I read less I understood the point.
How I can fix this code so it work? I meen a **practical working code** by using Type Erasure Idom or whatever workaround to make it possible to derived class to override the member method `write()` so do_write can call the right derived class method.

Comment: Not the answer, but your SFINAE unnecessarily requires `Iterable` to be default-constructible, and breaks if the user specifies the template parameters manually. A more robust solution would be `<class Iterable, decltype(void(std::declval<const Iterable &>().begin()), /*same for end*/ nullptr) = nullptr>`.

Comment: Why not convert the messages to strings using `std::ostringstream`, then give a vector of strings to a virtual function?

Comment: Actually Derived::write() is super complicated and should handle objects against a sqlite database. I just made it easy to focus on polymorphism!! solution.

Comment: Ok, so there is a finite number of types that it can support? Then pass a vector of `std::variant`s to the virtual function.

Comment: Thanks for idea. I thought about using std::variant or even std::any. But the method may receive data in map or set or vector or other std containers. Anyway I prefer a solution which mimics polymorphism and yet stands generic.

Comment: *"may receive data in map or set or vector or other std containers"* Yes, and I suggest converting it to a vector of variants first, then passing that to a virtual function. There's no silver bullet that would allow you to have a virtual template.

Comment: Why not simply move the virtual function into `Iterable` class hierarchy?

Comment: You want virtual template methods.  Too bad you can't.  There are techniques that solve problems similar to those that virtual template methods solve.  But you don't understand them.  And you have abstracted your problem down to "if I had virtual template methods I have a solution.  That is useless, because you don't have them.  You have an X/Y problem.  You need to actually describe your actual problem constraints.  I mean, why is iteratio happening in derived?  Why not iterate in base? I don't know, the problem is too abstract.